# Custom Gradle Plugin ID not found

Tags: plugins, build, gradle

I'm writing a Gradle plugin and I'm failing to get the `apply plugin:` command to work in the Gradle script that uses the plugin. I'm using Gradle 1.1.

I've build the plugin with `clean build` and I'm attempting to add it to the Gradle build via a flat repo for now. That seems to be working but Gradle isn't picking up that there is a plugin with the ID `test-plugin`. The project name in the plugin's `settings.gradle` is `test-plugin` and the properties file in `META-INF/gradle-plugins` is also `test-plugin.properties`. I'm not sure where else I can specify the plugin ID.

The `build.gradle` file in the project that is using the `test-plugin`:

```
repositories {
  flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: "../build/libs"
}

dependencies {
  compile 'test:test-plugin:0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'test-plugin'
```

Error from Gradle:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tmp'.
Plugin with id 'test-plugin' not found.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The plugin Jar has to be added as a *build script dependency*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: "../build/libs" }
    dependencies { classpath 'test:test-plugin:0.1' }
}

apply plugin: "test-plugin"
```

Comment: how do you add multiple plugins?

Comment: Add each plugin's `classpath` in the `dependencies` block, and have an `apply-plugin: "your-plugin"` line for each.

Comment: If used in the **multi-project**, make sure the buildscript block appear in **the build.gradle of the top level project** instead of those build.gradle of the sub projects

Answer (score 11):

If you want to implement a plugin into your buildscript, then you have two options.

**Option 1**
`apply plugin: YourCustomPluginClassName`

**Option 2**

```
plugins {
    id 'your.custom.plugin.id'
}
```

`apply plugin:` is used when specifying your plugin by its class name (ex. `apply plugin: JavaPlugin`)
`plugins { }` is used when specifying your plugin by its id (ex. `plugins { id 'java' }`)
See [Gradle Plugins by tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_plugins.htm) for reference

If you choose Option 1, the your custom plugin will need to be brought into your build script by 1 of 3 ways.

1. You can code it directly within your Gradle build script.
2. You can put it under **buildSrc** (ex. **buildSrc/src/main/groovy/MyCustomPlugin**).
3. You can import your custom plugin as a jar in your `buildscript` method.
   See [Gradle Goodness by Mr. Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/01/gradle-goodness-getting-information.html) for information about the `buildscript` method.

If you choose Option 2, then you need to create a plugin id. Create the following file **buildSrc/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/[desired.plugin.id].properties**.

Copy and paste `implementation-class=package.namespace.YourCustomPluginClassName` into your newly created **.properties** file. Replace `package.namespace.YourCustomPluginClassName` with the fully-qualified class name of your desired plugin class.

See [Custom Plugins by Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) for more info.

Comment: apply plugin: YourCustomPluginClassName seems to be a kind of deprecated way to use a plugin (2019).

Comment: `apply plugin:` is in many examples on the Gradle tutorial for [writing custom plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin)

Comment: Not a 'implementation-class=desired.plugin.id', but 'implementation-class=package.namespace.PluginClassName'

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova, from what I can see, you're absolutely correct. I've updated the answer to reflect your comment. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem with a custom plugin id not being found.  In my case, I simply forgot to add the 'src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins' properties file.  The name of the properties file must match the name of the plugin id with a '.properties' extension.

The file must contain a the line:

```
implementation-class=(your fully qualified plugin classpath)
```

That's the complete mechanism on how plugin id's get resolved to class names.

In addition the plugin needs to be added as a dependency as pointed out in the previous answer.  The android documentation states that you should use a name associated with your unique domain name. I.e.: the name 'test-plugin' is not really in good form, but an id like 'com.foo.gradle.test-plugin' would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your top-level `build.gradle` uses the correct `classpath` to refer to the path to the built **`*.jar`** file.

Some plugins, like [maven-publish](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/snapshots-gradle-maven-publish-plugin/), will build and save the jar to a specific location in `mavenLocal`, but the path may not be clear to see.

**You should look at the file path of the jar file, and ensure it matches your `classpath`, but the mapping is not immediately obvious:**

```js
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // This *MUST* match the local file path of the jar file in mavenLocal, which is:
    // ~/.m2/repository/com/company/product/plugin/product-gradle-plugin/1.0/product-gradle-plugin-1.0.jar
    classpath 'com.company.product.plugin:product-gradle-plugin:1.0'
  }
}
```

**Be careful not to use the wrong classpath, which can refer to a *directory* instead of the actual jar file; like this:**

```js
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // This is wrong, because it refers to the mavenLocal FOLDER "product-gradle-plugin",
    // instead of the jar FILE "product-gradle-plugin-1.0.jar"
    // However, a gradle sync will still resolve it as a valid classpath!!
    classpath 'com.company.product:product-gradle-plugin:1.0'
  }
}
```

More info:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-the-preferred-gradle-approach-to-locally-install-an-artifact-equivalent-to-mavens-install/5592
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html
- https://blog.codefx.org/tools/snapshots-gradle-maven-publish-plugin/
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Bonifacio2 wrote this is a path `META-INF/gradle-plugins` and shows in IntelliJ as `META-INF.gradle-plugins`. At all costs don't make the stupid mistake I did creating this directly as a directory `META-INF.gradle-plugins` because you are based on another sample, and never works. Another tip is copying also from another intelliJ project as this is what is added: `gradle-plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

hmm perhaps try;

```
    configure <org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle.JsonSchemaExtension> {
     this.sourceFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/schemas")
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only answer and provide some explanation.