# dokka not found in .gradlew command line build?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build a project that uses: https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager

When I run `./gradlew --assemble`, I get:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/path/to/SpannedGridLayoutManager/spannedgridlayoutmanager/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':spannedlm'.
> Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This is `SpannedGridLayoutManager/spannedgridlayoutmanager/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

task dokkaJavadoc(type: org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaAndroidTask) {
    delete "$rootDir/docs"

    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$rootDir/docs"

    externalDocumentationLink {
        url = new URL("https://developer.android.com/reference/")
    }

    includeNonPublic = false

    // Always recreate documentation
    outputs.upToDateWhen { return false }
}

afterEvaluate {
    if (project.hasProperty("javadocJar")) {
        tasks.javadocJar.dependsOn dokkaJavadoc
    }
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'spannedgridlayoutmanager'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.arasthel'
    libraryName = 'SpannedGridLayoutManager'
    artifact = 'spannedgridlayoutmanager'

    libraryDescription = 'A layout manager that will resize and reorder views based on a provided SpanSize.'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager.git'

    libraryVersion = '3.0.2'

    developerId = 'Arasthel'
    developerName = 'Jorge Martín Epsinosa'
    developerEmail = 'jorgemartinespinosa@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'MIT'
    licenseUrl = 'https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
    allLicenses = ["MIT"]
}

android {
    //compileSdkVersion 28
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion buildtools_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        //targetSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName libraryVersion
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    excludes = ['**/*.kt']
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

// Bintray Upload
apply from: '../gradle/tools/bintrayv1.gradle'
apply from: '../gradle/tools/installv1.gradle'
```

This is `SpannedGridLayoutManager/build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    //ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    ext.support_library_version = '28.0.0'
    //ext.dokka_version = '0.9.17'
    ext.dokka_version = '0.9.18'
    ext.buildtools_version = '28.0.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Aside - this looks like some plugin, that `gradlew` cannot retrieve online from its repository.

Is there a command to see all available plugins visible to `gradlew` for a given configuration? Something like `apt-show-versions -R -a` would list all packages available to `apt` in Debian?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I have it figured out, after reading a bit of [Custom Gradle Plugin ID not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569916/custom-gradle-plugin-id-not-found) .

The thing is - I could build `SpannedGridLayoutManager` with `./gradlew assemble`; but the error message I get, appears specifically when I build it as a dependent project.

The thing is: when I build `SpannedGridLayoutManager` standalone, first `SpannedGridLayoutManager/build.gradle` gets called, and defines `classpath`s in `dependencies` in `buildscript` - then when `SpannedGridLayoutManager/spannedgridlayoutmanager/build.gradle`, the plugin ids get resolved according to the `classpath`s defined earlier.

When I build my project, of course first `MyProject/build.gradle` runs - but it did not have the same `classpath`s set; so then when `MyProject/../SpannedGridLayoutManager/spannedgridlayoutmanager/build.gradle` gets processed - as a dependent project - the classpaths are not defined, and the plugin lookup fails.

So in my project, I basically had to add these two lines in `build.gradle` - here shown as a diff:

```
$ git diff build.gradle
diff --git a/build.gradle b/build.gradle
index b730fda..6a696c9 100644
--- a/build.gradle
+++ b/build.gradle
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.0"
+    ext.dokka_version = '0.9.18'
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
@@ -10,6 +11,7 @@ buildscript {
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
         classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
         classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4"
+        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
     }
 }
```

Of course, these two lines are copied verbatim from the original build file, `SpannedGridLayoutManager/build.gradle`.

Well, nice to get this fixed - but it would have been even better, with a better error message (or even, if `./gradlew --debug` would say something like `searching classpaths for ...` and dump out everything where it looked, and what it found).